Why am I not getting the amount I swapped
1 hour ago I swapped coins worth $2000 dollars but I did not recieve it into my wallet and my balance also decreased
I invested $0.94 into a coin called "daige" and it went up 100k+% and I had 2k I swapped it for solana, what may be the cause for me not getting it?

Did you try to check the transaction history and txid on solscan ? If so, could you please provide it here

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
